# How to resize LVM without data loss?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, lvm, vmware

[image: My partition map]

My lvm should be around 135GB but i see its only 74.5G how to increase it without data loss as my SDA is 150 GB .

Im using VMware for virtualization

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: Sure from next I will not post picture of text. Sorry for this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want is `lvextend` or `lvresize`. See `man lvextend` and `man lvresize` for the documentation. (The difference is that `lvextend` will only increase the size of an LV, whereas `lvresize` will also allow you to reduce it.)

Looking at your question, /dev/sda3 has 149GB allocated to it. This is the Physical Volume (PV) underlying the Volume Group (VG) that contains zero or more Logical Volumes (LV).

If you run `vgs` you'll see one volume group `ubuntu-vg` with a VSize of around 149GB and about 74GB VFree. If you `lvs` you'll see one logical volume `ubuntu-lv` with an LSize of 74.5GB. I would imagine that this contains a single filesystem, also around 74.5GB in size.

Typically, a set-up like this is intended to allow you to create multiple filesystems easily, and to extend them as necessary. So here, if you wanted to resize your filesystem to 100GB you'd also extend the LV to 100GB,

```
lvextend --size 100G --resizefs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv    # Increase size to 100 GB
```

You could have used a relative size increase too,

```
lvextend --size +25G --resizefs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv    # Increase size by 25 GB
```

As you can see, increasing the size of a filesystem is really easy.

On the other hand, be very very careful if you think you want to *reduce* the size of a filesystem and LV. If you get it wrong - even slightly - you can completely destroy the filesystem and its contents. It's worth reading up on this before trying it. Or just ensure you never need to reduce the size of a filesystem by increasing it only a little a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `lvextend` command:

```
$ lvextend --resizefs --size 148G
```

This will increase the size (to 148G in this case) of the logical volume and resize the filesystem within as well.

```
$ lvextend -l +100%FREE
```

will fill the entire available free space.

Extending the lvm is safe, shrinking lvm is tricky...

Comment: will this erase data on the volume ? also how to check what amount is remaining to be extended ?

Comment: It will not erase data on the volume.  Making volumes bigger is safe.  Making them smaller is not.